# Sqlite Query to retrieve distinct values with 0 in null fields

Tags: sql, sqlite

Trying to write a query to retrieve data with distinct months

Expected Result

```
months12    sev1    sev2
01  1   21
02  1   12
03  0   4
09  1   0
```

Getting Result

```
months12    sev1    sev2
01  1   21
01  1   12
01  1   4
02  1   21
02  1   12
02  1   4
03  1   21
03  1   12
03  1   4
09  1   21
09  1   12
09  1   4
```

Here is the query

```
select DISTINCT months12, sev1, sev2 from
(select Distinct strftime('%m', date(issue_reported)) months12 from tickets),
(select DISTINCT strftime('%m', date(issue_reported)) months, coalesce(count(*), 0) sev1
from tickets where ticket_severity="Sev 1" and strftime('%m', date(issue_reported)) in (select DISTINCT strftime('%m', date(issue_reported)) months from tickets) Group By ticket_severity, strftime('%m', date(issue_reported))),
(select DISTINCT strftime('%m', date(issue_reported)) months1, coalesce(count(*), 0) sev2
from tickets where ticket_severity="Sev 3" and strftime('%m', date(issue_reported)) in (select DISTINCT strftime('%m', date(issue_reported)) months from tickets) Group By ticket_severity, strftime('%m', date(issue_reported)))
```

Comment: Post the data that produce these results and clarify what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need conditional aggregation:

```
select strftime('%m', date(issue_reported)) months12, 
  sum(ticket_severity = 'Sev 1') sev1,
  sum(ticket_severity = 'Sev 2') sev2
from tickets
group by months12
```